# bufferedwriter refuses to write to text file(Java)

Tags: java, file, writer

Whenever I call my method in my code, despite opening and closing my BufferedWriter correctly(I think) it still refuses to print to the text file that it is meant to print to
Here is my code :

```
public Student(String nameInput, String gradeInput) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Students.txt"));
        name = nameInput;
        grade = gradeInput;
        o.write(gradeInput);
        o.newLine();
        o.write(nameInput);
        o.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: first you need to add a return type in your method, or if Student is  a return type you need to specify your method-name

Comment: where you are calling the method Student() can you show that code

Comment: no need to add the return in that method

Comment: How are you calling this constructor? (From the signature I think this is a constructor of a `Student` class.) Because writing `new Student("name", "grade");` in an otherwise empty `main` method and running it creates the "Students.txt" file with the correct content.

Comment: @NamrataShukla I believe it's a constructor

Comment: How do you know it refuses to write to the text file? is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void Student(String nameInput, String gradeInput) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter o = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Students.txt"));
        String name = nameInput;
        String grade = gradeInput;
        o.write(gradeInput);
        o.newLine();
        o.write(nameInput);
        o.close(); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student("ABC","A");
    }

}
```

Comment: Mr.Rishabh have made the answer

Comment: Resources should be closed in a finally block! JIC!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `o.flush()` before closing the `BufferedWriter` i.e.,`o.close()`